# How to get the complete document path in firebase firestore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I managed to get all the documents and document IDs inside all 'sheets' collection in firestore.
Refer to below code -

```
const baseRef = admin.firestore().collectionGroup("sheets").where("date", "==", date);
const querySnap = await baseRef.get();
const docSnap = querySnap.docs;

docSnap.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log("DOC ID ---->>>", doc.id);
    // Here I want to get all the required documents from 'members' subcollection present inside this      document
});
```

Now each of these documents contain a subcollection called 'members'. I want only documents from 'members' collection where "memberId" is equal to 'memberId'. How can I get those documents?

I tried the following code but it didn't worked -

```
const baseRef = admin.firestore().collectionGroup("sheets").where("date", "==", date).collectionGroup("members").where("memberId", "==", memberId);
const querySnap = await baseRef.get();
const docSnap = querySnap.docs;

docSnap.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log("DOC ID ---->>>", doc.id);
});
```

It returned following error -

```
admin.firestore(..).collectionGroup(..).....is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot define a `Query` by calling twice the `collectionGroup()` method as you do with:

```
const baseRef = admin.firestore().collectionGroup("sheets").where("date", "==", date).collectionGroup("members").where("memberId", "==", memberId);
```

---

One solution would be to replicate the `date` field in the `member` documents (i.e. copying the field value from the parent `sheet` docs to their `member` children docs) and define the Query as follows:

```
const baseRef = admin.firestore().collectionGroup("members").where("memberId", "==", memberId).where("date", "==", date);
```

Note that you'll need to build a composite index and that you should not have other subcollections named `members` in your database.